# What is the AIX's `ps -T PID` equivalent for Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, aix, ps

I really like the way `ps -T PID` works on AIX.  It shows you a nice tree of processes in the right side, and their PID, PPID and other info in the left side.  In AIX docs, the `-T` flag reads *Displays the process hierarchy rooted at a given pid in a tree format using ASCII art.*

**Example: ps -T 40632**

```
   40632      -  0:00    |\--telnetd
   40232  pts/2  0:00    |    \--ksh
   32910  pts/2  0:00    |        \--dbx
  987990  pts/2  0:00    |            \--a.out
```

**Without using `pstree`, is there a way to get the same (or slightly different) output using Linux's `ps`?**  It doesn't matter if post-processing of the results is required (using `awk`, `sed`, `grep`, etc...), I just want a way to show the results like the AIX's version, that is, generating a tree of processes showing the PID, the childs, the children's childs, and so on.  Besides the fact that Linux's `ps -T` does not show the format I want, it only output the proceses directly related with the PID (PID + direct childs).

I have tried `pstree`, but can't make it look like this at all - seems like it only support to have the PID printed beside the name of the process and its arguments, but can't print those in another *pane*, like AIX's version does.

By the way, I'm using `Debian 3.2.35-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and `procps-ng version 3.3.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple process tree use `ps -acxef -o pid,time,command`, to get full command lines displayed, leave `-c` out ie. use `ps -axef -o pid,time,command`.